# Mac OS X 10.10 MacPorts Python select

Tags: python, bash, macos, macports

I installed Python 2.7 on my Mac with MacPorts (https://www.macports.org/).

After the installation I set the $PATH variable to include the MacPorts directory which worked fine:

```
$ echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Then I set the version I want to use with the python-selector:

```
$ sudo port select --set python python27
```

from this list:

```
$ sudo port select --list python
Password:
Available versions for python:
    none
    python26-apple
    python27 (active)
    python27-apple
    python34
```

Now to test, if everything worked fine I do this and get the strange result:

```
$ which python
python is /opt/local/bin/python
python is /usr/bin/python
```

So now I am not sure what's going on. Python terminal uses the right version and everything seems to be working so far. But I was expecting only one python version as active. Is this bad? Is there anything I can or must do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where your `which` comes from (check with `which which`) and whether you implicitly pass any flags to `which` (check with `type which`), but that's the output I'd expect if you called `which -a python`.

Btw, if you're trying to find out what your shell is going to do when you type `python`, you should use `type python`, which is a shell built-in. It has the advantage of using the shell's cache (so it won't show you `/opt/local/bin/python` while typing `python` still gives you `/usr/bin/python` because you have not run `hash -r` or opened a new shell) and takes shell aliases and functions into account.

Long story short: Looks fine the way it is.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time for this rather trivial problem. I had "which" aliased to "type -all". Now I know, why I got the two versions.